# Getting a specific option element from a select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select list like

```
<select id="list">
   <option value="">Select something</option>
   <option value="1">Uno</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
   <option value="3">Trois</option>
</select>
```

And with jQuery I want to select the second option, get the value and put it into a hidden input.

Im doing it this way:

```
$('#IdOfTheInput').val( $($('#list option')[1]).attr('value'); );
```

But I don't know if there is a better way to do it, since is a really common thing and it smells suboptimal.

Thanks!

Comment: $('#list option').get(1).value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is to select the option by index then you can use [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) and use [.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/)

```js
$('#IdOfTheInput').val($('#list option').eq(1).val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="list">
  <option value="">Select something</option>
  <option value="1">Uno</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Trois</option>
</select>

<input id="IdOfTheInput" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery `eq()` selector.

```
 $("inputSelector").val($("SelectSelector option:eq(1)").val());
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `options` and `value` to get the value.

```
var option = document.getElementById("list").options[1].value; // return 1"
```

Comment: Neither related on getting the value nor on the explicitly asked use of jquery.

Comment: @JavaScript I have modified the ans to get the value. Why ans in JavaScript because in future there will be people who will look for solution in JavaScript too. So at one place both solutions are present.